# Is it possible to use an object as the parameter of a UDF in Oracle/SQL?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

Is there a way to use an object as an input parameter of a UDF ? As I am trying bellow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fv_group as object(
fv NUMBER,
group_number INTEGER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fv_group_array IS VARRAY(100) OF fv_group;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_groupby(FV NUMBER, fv_and_group IN OUT fv_group_array) IS
    g fv_group;
BEGIN
    IF fv < 15 THEN
        g := fv_group(fv,1);
    ELSE
        g := fv_group(fv,2);
    END IF;

    fv_and_group.extend(1);
    fv_and_group(fv_and_group.last) := g;
END;
/

declare
    obj fv_group_array := fv_group_array();
begin
    select insert_groupby(c.fv,obj)
    from   cophir c;
end; 
/
```

When I execute the code above I get the error 
**PL/SQL: ORA-00904**.

PS .. Table cophir:

```
SQL> desc cophir
 Nome                          Tipo

 FV                         NUMBER(38)

 ID                         NUMBER(38)
```

Comment: How is `cophir` defined?

Comment: Added this information to the question.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question: yes, you can pass objects to a UDF. But that's not your problem.

In the anonymous block at the end of your code you've got the statement

```
select insert_groupby(c.fv,obj)
  from   cophir c;
```

However, `insert_groupby` is a procedure. Procedures cannot be called from SQL statements because they don't return a value. You might be able to change `insert_groupby` into a function, but you'll need to figure out what it should return.

Another option is to use a loop:

```
declare
  obj fv_group_array := fv_group_array();
begin
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT fv FROM cophir)
  LOOP
    insert_groupby(aRow.fv, obj);
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Best of luck.